# Jssor Grid Slider Customization

Tags: jssor

Jssor: Nice work!

I would like to build a grid slider in the following way (based on the jssor grid slider example):

1. 1 vertical carousal contains 3 horizontal carousals (exactly like the example)
2. 3 horizontal carousals (h1, h2, & h3) have a number of photos.
3. The first photo of each horizontal carousal is static (would not slide out, but would slide up and down).

Could it be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you please draw a picture of the layout?

Answer (score 0):

Given a main slider (vertical) with 3 slides, and each slide contains a child slider (horizontal).

As each slide (of the main slider) is fully customizable. You can place a static image and a child slider (horizontal) in each slide.

Hope this help.